Pythonにおけるimport文と関数の呼び出しについて
先日import文によってライブラリやモジュールをインポートし、関数を呼び出す方法を学んだのですが、いくつか疑問に思ったことと、確認したいことがあるので、以下に箇条書きします。

importの後には、使用したい関数が属する階層構造のうち、ライブラリ、パッケージ、モジュールのいずれかを、目的により、任意で記述できるという認識で問題ないか。
特定の関数のみを使用したい場合、fromをあわせて用いるが、fromの後にライブラリ名を記述するべきかパッケージ名を記述すべきかモジュール名を記述するべきかを、どのようにして判断するのか。
関数を呼び出す際、 ライブラリ名.関数名 や モジュール名.関数名 と記述すると習ったが、 numpy.random.randint() のように ライブラリ名.モジュール名.関数名 と記述する場合があるのはなぜか。


マルチポスト => https://qiita.com/sasaki159/questions/5b96a2b03ac50f7fb82a


importの後には、使用したい関数が属する階層構造のうち、ライブラリ、パッケージ、モジュールのいずれかを、目的により、任意で記述できるという認識で問題ないか。

はい。通常(※)はその認識で問題ありません。
※文脈によってライブラリの示すスコープが広範であったりすると認識の齟齬が生じるかもしれません。この回答ではライブラリをpip installなどの手段で追加した外部パッケージと想定しています。

・特定の関数のみを使用したい場合、fromをあわせて用いるが、fromの後にライブラリ名を記述するべきかパッケージ名を記述すべきかモジュール名を記述するべきかを、どのようにして判断するのか。

ライブラリ/パッケージの構造や組み合わせ、サンプルコード、コーディング規約、スタイル、好み、その日の体調に応じて判断します。
個人的な意見ですが、最初は公式のサンプルコードと同様に記述すると誤字が発生しにくく学習が進みやすいです。
例えばpandasはユーザガイドに記載の通り、下記のように最上位モジュールを別名で指定します。
import pandas as pd

Qiitaなどの一般サイトでもその構成にならっている例が多いので、その点でも都合が良いです。
またできるだけ他のインポートと名前が重複しないように、パッケージ名を記述することも悪くない判断基準です。
例えば下記のようにos.path.join関数と自作モジュールのjoin関数が重複した時はos.path.joinが使えなくなります。
from os.path import join
from my_package.my_module.my_module2 import join

それを避けるために冗長になりすぎない範囲でfromを記述すると下記のようになります。
from os import path
from my_package.my_module import my_module2

print(path.join("C:\\","hoge"))
print(my_module2.join("fuga","piyo"))


・関数を呼び出す際、ライブラリ名.関数名やモジュール名.関数名と記述すると習ったが、numpy.random.randint()のようにライブラリ名.モジュール名.関数名と記述する場合があるのはなぜか。

上記の通りです。重複回避や規約などが理由となります。
numpyの他に標準パッケージにもrandom.randintがあります。

参照情報として、importに関してPEP8(Python の標準ライブラリに含まれているPythonコードのコーディング規約)に記述があります。
推奨するimport順やワイルドカード(*)の非推奨などが記述されていますが、fromでどこまで書くのかについては重複時の例くらいしか書かれていません。
最初から一貫性こだわりすぎると学習が進まなくなったりストレスがたまったりしますので、ざっくりと「こういうものか」と思いながら正解がないことを受けとめるのも時には必要かもしれません。
最後に、スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！
マルチポストをする際はその旨を記載していただきますようお願いいたします。
マルチポストとは何ですか？

返信ありがとうございます。おしえていただいた方法に従い、一貫性にこだわりすぎず、とりあえず学習を進めることを優先します。
